# How can I change the font-size of one select box option text (select2) with css?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-select2

I want to change the font-size of one of my select boxes. But it is not working:

http://jsfiddle.net/jEADR/3717/

```
 <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.2/select2.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.2/select2.min.js"></script>



<select  id="e1" class="select2" style="width:300px">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
        <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
        <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>

    <select  id="e2" class="select2" style="width:300px">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
        <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
        <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
<style>
    #e2 .select2-results{
      font-size:4px;
    }
</style>

<script>
$(".select2").select2();
</script>
```

Comment: Try `#e2.select2` -- remove the space

Comment: @ovokuro Not working: http://jsfiddle.net/jEADR/3719/

Comment: How about use the full select2 script in here `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.full.min.js`

Comment: I'm not sure if you are really expecting this. Just give a try http://jsfiddle.net/jEADR/3727/

Comment: @Venky No I expect both select boxes to be select2 formatted

Comment: oddly enough, if you set Body{font-size: 72px} it works, partly.

Comment: @Stavm But then the font-size changes for all select boxes

Comment: @Stavm, sadly it affects all `p` tags inside the body.

Comment: do you want to change the font-size in both selects e1 and e2 or just one?

Comment: @Chiller Just in one (and only the option text). This is my problem

Comment: Try `#s2id_e2` http://jsfiddle.net/jEADR/3731/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/jEADR/3730/

```
<select  id="e1" class="select2" style="width:300px">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
        <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
        <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>

    <select  id="e2" class="select2" style="width:300px">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
        <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
        <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>

<script>
$(".select2").select2();
$("#e2").select2({ dropdownCssClass: "myFont" });
</script>

.myFont{
  font-size:4px;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I see that option here at https://select2.org/configuration/options-api but I get `Uncaught Error: No select2/compat/dropdownCss`. Maybe this is the problem: https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/2879#issuecomment-293422517

Answer (score 6):

The best answer I've discovered for this problem is to wrap the select in a `div` and set the CSS as follows.

CSS:

```
.fooSelect
{
    display:inline;
}
.fooSelect .select2-selection__rendered
{
    font-size:1.2em;
}
```

Other code:

```
<div class="fooSelect"><select  id="e1" class="select2" style="width:300px">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
    <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
    <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select></div>


<script>
    $("#e1").select2();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

[My change on here](http://jsfiddle.net/baghdasarov94/jEADR/4351/)

Just add to every option class and use it.

On js file

```
$("#e1 option,#e2 option").addClass("font-size-4");
$(".select2").select2();
```

On Css file

```
.font-size-4{
   font-size:4px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By trying your fiddle I came out with this answer also by the help of chrome dev tool. Also `select2` needs [jQuery](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js) in order to run.

See sample below:

```js
$(".sample").select2({
 width: '200px',
  theme: "classic"
});
```

```css
/* Select option */
.select2-results__option { 
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<select class="sample">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
ul.select2-results__options li{
  font-size:13px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i use this. maybe can help :

```
.select2-dropdown {
   font-size: 12px;
}
```

Comment: Hi Dhano

Please update your question to be specific, with what you want to archive, what you've already searched and a minimal executable sample of what you have. 
SO can not help if you do not state your problem. Furthermore, try to google and search the SO for your problem first. 
Welcome to SO 
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple {
        font-size: 11px;
    }
```

i tried it and worked

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score -1):

Use the CSS selectors below. But I changed the font-size value for this example, since some browsers won't display a font at 4px (there are minimum settings)

```css
#e2.select2, #e2.select2 option {
  font-size:32px;
}
```

```html
<select  id="e1" class="select2" style="width:300px">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
        <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
        <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>

    <select  id="e2" class="select2" style="width:300px">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
        <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
        <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: I guess it won't work using the `select2 script and css`.

Comment: @Johannes But I explicitly asked to have a SELECT2 formatted select box! Why should I remove the formatting??

Comment: not the formatting, the jQuery - you didn't mention the jQuery at all in your question, you only had it in the fiddle

Comment: @Johannes, select2 is a jquery replacement for html select boxes. The script there is important to run the custom selectbox.

Comment: So actually this is a Javascript question. You should list that Jacascript in your question. I answered your question by what you posted...

Comment: @Johannes But I was hoping that this is working with css

Comment: @Johannes I was asking for select2 selectbox

Answer (score -3):

```
 #e2.select2 {
   font-size: 25px;
}​
```

Comment: Remove the javascript as well